# Rhino JS incorrectly converting JSON string to object during function return

Tags: javascript, json, ant, rhino

I'm using Ant's 'script language="javascript"' tag to run javascript with Rhino Js on JDK 1.7.  I have recently encountered an issue where the type of my variable is being incorrectly changed when it is returned from a function.

I have a very small helper function that reads files using the java interfaces.

```
        importClass(java.io.File);
        importClass(java.io.FileReader);
        function readFile(directory, filename) {
            var file = new File(directory, filename);
            println("Found file: " + directory + "/" + filename);
            var fr = new FileReader(file);
            var fileText = "";
            var nextChar = fr.read();
            while(nextChar != -1)
            {
                fileText += String.fromCharCode(nextChar);
                nextChar = fr.read();
            }
            println('In readFile result has type ' + typeof fileText);
            return fileText;
        }
```

This works fine on most machines, however on some subset of linux boxes, when this function is used to read a file that contains valid JSON, the return type of the variable is changed from "string" to "object".

```
// manifest.json is a file containing valid JSON.
var manifestText = readFile(extensionDirectory, "manifest.json");
println('After return result has type ' + typeof manifestText);
// The output of the above is:
// [script] In readFile result has type string
// [script] After return result has type object
```

Normally I would chalk this up as an oddity and just check the type and convert the object back to a string with JSON.stringify, however... trying to call JSON.stringify on the new "object" fails.

```
javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Java class "[Ljava.lang.annotation.Annotation;" has no public instance field or method named "toJSON". (<Unknown source>#18) in <Unknown source> at line number 18
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to force Rhino JS to correctly preserve the variable type through the function call, I'd really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to force the string type by wrapping the function call in the global string constructor.

```
var manifestText = String(readFile(dir, filename));
```

I still don't like the implicit type conversion happening here, but this at least solves the problem for me.